# how to pass data service into components in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-services

I'm requesting from api to get data in service, but don't got how to get those data at components? I have tried to google but didn't found any solutions.

**service file**

```
login(email:string, pwd:string):void{
  this.loginModule.verifyEmailLogin(email, pwd, (data)=>{
    console.log('user login data==>, ',data)
    return data;
  })
}
```

Here I got to data in my console

**componets file js**

```
saveLoginForm() :void{
  //console.log(this.loginForm);
  console.log('Saved: ' + JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value));
  this._userAuthService.login(this.loginForm.value.userEmail, this.loginForm.value.userPwd)

}
```

Comment: Seems like you are talking about dependency injection , https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern...

Ah , you are already using it , my bad.. but you are not returning anything from your login method of service , then why are you expecting it to send you some value.

Ideally, when you make an http call in angular , it returns you observable data which you can subscribe to and listen for changes in component.

Comment: you need to make it observable in order to subscribe data into your component file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and return a `Promise` to resolve the data in callback of `this.loginModule.verifyEmailLogin`.

```
login(email:string, pwd:string): Promise<any>{
  return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
    this.loginModule.verifyEmailLogin(email, pwd, (data)=>{
      console.log('user login data==>, ',data)
      //return data;
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Then get the resolved data at component via `Promise.then`

```
this._userAuthService.login(this.loginForm.value.userEmail, this.loginForm.value.userPwd).then(data => {
  // deal anything with the data
})
```

---

Return an `Observable` will also solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @Pengyy it's working fine for me but there is any more solution about this

Comment: @RohitAzad I think you should return `Observable` or `Promise` at your `loginModule.verifyEmailLogin` function. This will also make it easy to observer it's response and also can solve your problem.

Comment: @Pendgyy Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `loginModule.verifyEmailLogin` returns the observable from your http call

**service file**

```
login(email:string, pwd:string): Observable<any>{
    return this.loginModule.verifyEmailLogin(email, pwd, (data))
}
```

**componets file js**

```
saveLoginForm() :void{
    this._userAuthService.login(this.loginForm.value.userEmail, this.loginForm.value.userPwd)
       .subscribe(
           (data) => console.log(data),
           (error) => console.log(error)
       )

  }
```